# Migrating existing project to Android Studio 3.3 Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have just installed Android Studio 3.3 and opened my existing project. It unfortunately finds out that there are run configuration problem. Would you please tell me the way to fix or reinstall?

[image]

When I import the project with gradle , close and open the project again ,  it shows the following errors on the log  :

```
2:16 PM Unable to save plugin settings: The plugin org.jetbrains.android failed to save settings and has been disabled. Please restart Android Studio

2:16 PM Gradle sync failed: 'Gradle: org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.10.8@aar' already disposed: --------------Creation trace: 
                java.lang.Throwable: 1548137815181
                at com.intellij.openapi.util.TraceableDisposable.<init>(TraceableDisposable.java:45)
                at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryImpl.<init>(LibraryImpl.java:102)
                at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryImpl.<init>(LibraryImpl.java:74)
                at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase$LibraryModel.createLibrary(LibraryTableBase.java:298)
                at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase$LibraryModel.createLibrary(LibraryTableBase.java:291)
                at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase$LibraryModel.createLibrary(LibraryTableBase.java:285)
                at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.createLibrary(AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.java:257)
                at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.AndroidMod... (show balloon)

2:17 PM Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio
```

Answer (score 3):

The Android plugin got disabled in Settings | Plugins. You need to re-enable it.

Comment: I have just edit the question. Would you please tell what to fix ?

Comment: I am using the Mac Version